# Mapping actuator endpoints outside of base path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-actuator

I try to achieve the following:

in my application, the health endpoint should be mapped to `/health` all the other endpoints however should be mapped to `/actuator/**`.

From the documentation, I understand that for mapping health to a top level path, I should set

```
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/
```

But this has the effect of mapping all endpoint to root level paths, which is not what I want.